# Uniform convergence of $\sqrt{x^2+n^2}^{-1}-n^{-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Assume the following sum:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+n^2}}-\frac{1}{n}\right),
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}$. The problem is to determine whether the sum converges uniformly, i.e. whether there exists $s(x)$ such as $\sum f_n(x) \rightrightarrows s(x)$. 
My approach is following: I show $f_n \rightarrow 0$ for every $x$, as 
$$
f_n \sim \frac{1}{n^3}, \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f_n}{n^{-3}} = -\frac{x^2}{2}.
$$
Then I can show $f_n \rightrightarrows 0$, as 
$$
|f_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{n}, \forall x,
$$
thus the sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to zero, and here I got stuck. 
Is my approach correct? Could you help me find out on which interval the sum converges uniformly? Is the convergence absolute/local? What is the prescription of $s(x)$?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: It is probably easier to deal with $F(x)$ written this way: $$ F(x)=-x^2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+x^2}\left(n+\sqrt{n^2+x^2}\right)}$$

Comment: Then you may notice that the $n$-th term of the series is bounded by $\frac{1}{2n^2}$, and $\left\{\frac{1}{2n^2}\right\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a summable sequence, hence we have uniform convergence over any compact subset of the real line.

Comment: Took me a while to get it, now I see: $f_n = \frac{n-\sqrt{n^2+x^2}}{n\sqrt{n^2+x^2}} = \frac{n-\sqrt{n^2+x^2}}{n\sqrt{n^2+x^2}} \frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+x^2}}{n+\sqrt{n^2+x^2}}= \frac{-x^2}{\sqrt{n^2+x^2}\left(n+\sqrt{n^2+x^2}\right)}$. It seems to be a good trick, I will look at it.

Comment: Then $f_n(x) = -x^2 g_n(x)$. By the way, the series $g_n$ is bounded as $|g_n| \leq \frac{1}{2n^3}$, isn't it?

Comment: $g_n$ is bounded because $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2n^2}$ is convergent.

Comment: Ah, now I see. We both missed a little mistake: $f_n = \frac{-x^2}{n\sqrt{n^2+x^2}\left(n+\sqrt{n^2+x^2}\right)}$ - we missed the $n$ in the denominator. And yes, the bound $|g_n| \leq \frac{1}{2n^2}$ holds and I agree with your logic, I just wanted to note that the bound can be made stronger: $|g_n|\leq \frac{1}{2n^3}$.

Comment: No, it cannot be made stronger. We have $f_n(x)=-x^2\sum_{n\geq 1}g_n(x)$, where $$ g_n(x)=\frac{1}{(n+\sqrt{n^2+x^2})\sqrt{n^2+x^2}}\leq \frac{1}{2n^2}.$$

Answer (score -1):

For fixed $x$,

$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}((1+(\frac{x}{n})^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}})-\frac{1}{n}$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}(1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2}{n^2}(1+\epsilon(n)))-\frac{1}{n}$$

$$=-\frac{x^2}{2n^3}(1+\epsilon(n))$$

thus the series $\sum f_n(x)$ converges.

Now let $a>0$.

for large enough $n$

$\forall x\in [-a,a]$

$|f_n(x)|\leq \frac{a^2}{2n^3}$

thus the series converges uniformly at

$ [-a,a]$ and also at $[a,b]$ but not on $\mathbb R.$

Comment: You are tacitly assuming that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ at $x=0$ is $+\infty$, that is false. You cannot prove or disprove uniform convergence through that.

Comment: i used equivalence

Comment: My objection still holds. You used a Taylor expansion at $0$, that does not converge to the actual value of the function if $x$ is too large in absolute value. *Equivalence* holds in a neighbourhood of zero, not on the whole real line.

Comment: no, Taylor expansion when $n\to \infty$

Comment: Still the same objection. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+n^2}}$ is not an entire function, regarded as a function of $x$ or $n$.

Comment: I expand $f_n(x)$ for $x$ fixed, to get an equivalent when $n\ to \infty$

Comment: But if you work for a fixed $x$, how can you prove a uniform convergence claim, that, by the very definition of *uniform*, means *for every $x$ in some set$\ldots$* ?

Comment: Such (local) arguments work for proving pointwise convergence, but that, here, is quite trivial.

Comment: You begin by the pointwise convergence and then the uniform.

Comment: But a local argument (pointwise) has no chance to prove something global (uniform).

Comment: The expansion gives an other expression of $f_n(x)$  .

Comment: I am tired of arguing. My opinion still is that yours is not an answer, and uniform convergence over any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be simply proved by exploiting my observations in the comments under the main question, not involving any Taylor series.

Comment: If you don't understand, i am sorry. bye.

Comment: I don't think your second line is correct. I think it should be

Comment: $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\left[1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2}{n^2}\left(1+\epsilon(n,x)\right)\right]-\frac{1}{n}$, i.e. the epsilon $\epsilon(n,x)$ depends also on $x$. It seems that you obtained the correct result, but I don't understand what you mean by 'I used equivalence' - could you explain it, please? I want to fully understand your approach.